# How to override the fncatelog.php function in cscart

Tags: php, cs-cart

I need to override the fncatelog.php in cscart in my new addon.

```
 My addon files :-

  1.  app/addons/newaddon/frontend/controllers/frontend/categories.post.php
  2. design/themes/response/templates/addons/newaddon/overrides/blocks/product_filters/original.tpl

  In func.php 

          I need to override the fn_get_filters_products_count() this function in my newaddon.
```

How can I do . Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can not override the whole function. But you can use hooks to modify input arguments and returning argument. 
In your case hooks are

1. get_filters_products_count_pre to modify input args,
2. get_filters_products_count_before_select_filters to change query param

To know more about cscart hooks please use this link -  http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/developer_guide/core/coding_standards/hooks.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following hook to modify data returning by this function:
get_filters_products_count_pre
get_filters_products_count_before_select_filters
get_product_filter_fields

You can read more about hooks system in CS-Cart at the http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.2.x/addons/hooking/index.html page.